# How to embed CINT into a C++ app on Windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, interpreter, embedding

I would like to know how to embed CINT into a C++ code on Windows 7 or NT.

On windows7, I need to write a C++ program that reads a C++ program from an input file, runs it and counts how many lines of code were executed during the run. I found the best way to do this would be by (1) updating the read program code so that once a command in it is executed a counter value is increased (for commands like return or break the counter value will be increased before execution), and (2) executing the updated program with a C++ interpreter, reading the counter value once it returns. 
I would appreciate other approaches to solve this issues.

I searched the web and found CINT would be the correct interpreter to use (although old). I downloaded it from the ROOT home page, installed it and went throw the TestApp demo, but building it I got a linkage error I didn't find how to solve. Hence I need your help.

The best would be if someone can provide me a project embedding CINT in C++ code on windows, so I can test on my machine, and find my mistake.

I will appreciate any other valueable input as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the linker error that you are getting? What compiler (MSVC, perhaps)?

Comment: Thanks for your commment. I am using MSVC 2010.    Please let me know, calling makecint is required to embed CINT into C++ code?           I instealled CINT by using the binary distribution. The README indicates this installation's limitation:    With the binary distribution, you can only use cint C++ interpreter. In order to use makecint, you must compile cint from source.                      I am not sure if I need makecint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more reasonable alternative would be to modify the source file as you read it. For instance, when this is your input:

```
void foo() {
  std::cout << "Hello";
  std::cout << " World" << std::endl;
}
```

you transform it to this:

```
static int LineCounter = 0;
extern "C" int getLineCounter() { return LineCounter; }

extern "C" void foo() {
  ++LineCounter;
  std::cout << "Hello";
  ++LineCounter;
  std::cout << " World" << std::endl;
}
```

and pass that to a compiler. Compile it into a DLL, call `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress("foo")`, and `GetProcAddress("getLineCounter")`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Please let me know- is it possible to compile into a DLL on runtime, and then to load the DLL? If it is, then how to do so?

Comment: The compilation part is fairly easy - just call the compiler - and the loading of the DLL is explained in the last line. But TBH if you need to ask that, this whole project is probably a bit above your paygrade. Do you know where exactly in the source you should add a `++LineCounter` ? Do you know how many "commands" there are in `<< std::endl` ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This project is a bit above my paygrade so I am asking for your help. Could you please explain how to call the compiler? Also, I need to add a '++LineCounter' after executing each line in the given source, not after executing each command. For a line A that its execution leads to a line B where B isn't A's following line in the text, I will add the '++LineCounter' before the line A. Thanks

Comment: OK I got it: I need to use CreateProcess to run cl.exe to build obj file from the updated code, and then to call CreateProcess to run link.exe on the created obj, with a flag so it is created as a DLL, and to call this DLL functionality from my code as you described above. What are the command line options for cl and link to do what I want?

Comment: CL can call the linker for you. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks. The other program I want to build into a DLL contains the following `DllMain` function:

`extern "C" BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    return TRUE;
}`

and I added `/Entry:DllMain` to the link options.
I get the following linkage errors: 
`LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DllMain
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase

Could you please let me know how to fix it? Thanks